# Want to remove powered by wordpress in fotter in wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

Problem : - Want to remove hotter tag .
I have tried to clear this tag in wedget but not successful . and in theme codes i have try to find out many time but unsucessful .

My website is  `aarcityforeste.com` and i want to remove Power by wordpress link in fotter and not able to clear pls help me .

Comment: It is somehow not right. Your site is indeed powered by WordPress, you should do the content management yourself if you do not want to be "powered by" anything else.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale WordPress is released under the GPLv2 which allows modification, so it's not 'not right'.

Comment: I know that @harris , that's why the "somehow". I just can't see the point in removing credits. It's just about recognizing the great tool that boosted your work after all.

Answer (score 0):

In your footer.php file (under appearance -> editor), look for the line. All you need to do is remove it.

Edit: This line to be specific:

```
<?php do_action( 'simplecatch_credits' ); ?>
```